# count collection of subset containing all elements of set

Tags: set, subset, combinations

Given a set S(M) containing M 1's, count all collections of non-empty subsets such that union of each collection generates S(M). Also cardinality of subset can be K where 1< K<=M and M can take values upto 10^5.

```
S(M) = {1,1,1,1}, K = 2.

possible collections can be 
{{1,1},{1,1}},
{1},{1},{1,1}},
{{1,1},{1},{1}}
```

I already had a look into few answers but I believe they are different than mine.

I have also read [Stirling number of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) but I am still looking to incorporate the condition for cardinality of subset in that formula.

I had coded a possible recursive solution which is not working for large values of M.

Please let me know if anybody needs more information.

Any Help or guidance will be appreciated.

Regards

Ajay

Comment: Do you mean _multi_sets?  Why are {{1},{1},{1,1}} and {{1,1},{1},{1}} considered distinct?

Comment: In this case position matters.

Comment: Then it sounds like the fact that all the elements are 1 is irrelevant.  Making them be distinct removes the complications of multisets and, if I understand correctly, of "position".

Comment: I didn't get your point. If we write cardinality of both the subsets than it would be {1,1,2} and {2,1,1}. For this case, I believe I can use permutations and combinations to get all the number of combination of {1,1,2} i.e. 3. Also, if you know any solution which can solve the problem by considering {{1},{1},{1,1}} and {{1,1},{1},{1}} as same than please let me know.

Comment: I probably still don't understand the exact problem you're trying to solve.  Can you edit to use the strictest terminology you can (set/multiset/sequence/...?) and in particular explain the role of _K_ further?

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in solving the question.

Comment: K is used to restrict the cardinality of subset. In above example, {{1,1},{1,1}},{{1},{1},{1,1}}  are valid solutions whereas {{1,1,1},{1}} and {{1,1,1,1}} corresponds to an invalid solution as the cardinality has increased. It is not a case of multiset as in multiset the total number of elements in a collection of subsets can get increased from total number of elements present in the given set. Let me know if you need more clarity on this. Also, If needed I can provide all the solutions for the above example.

Answer (score 0):

*If* I understand the terminology in this question correctly, you are asking how many ways there are to divide a sequence ABCDEFGHIJ... of length *M* into words (e.g., ABC DE FGH IJ ...) each with a length no greater than *K*.  (For the example given, the answer is five: A B C D, A B CD, A BC D, AB C D, and AB CD.)  This is a sort of dual of the problems solved by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), since the restriction is on the sizes of the subsets rather than on their number.

I've made no attempt at a closed-form solution for this, but a direct [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) attack works in O(*M*^2 *K*) time: let *C*_n be the number of possibilities for the first *n* letters.  *C*_0=1, and *C*_n is 0 for all *n*<0.  For *n*>0, we have *C*_n=sum(*i*=[1..*K*]) *C*_(*n*-*i*).  Just compute the values in order until you reach *C*_M.  (It is sufficient, of course, to keep the last *K* values in a queue used as a SIPO [shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register).)

Note that the values get large very fast: with *M*=100 and *K*=2, I get 5.7e20 possibilities; changing *K* to 10 gives 6.1e29.  The *M* of 10^5 mentioned (with *K*=2 again) gives 4.2e20898.  I therefore included the extra factor of *M* in the complexity corresponding to arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be

```
Given M and K

Find the max number of divisions(subsets)
Find the min number of divisions(subsets)

Iterate from max to min using i
-Apply DP to find different combinations of sizes of subsets. 
-A permutation of each combination should yield a count for that number of combinations(i). 
-Sum up all the counts.
```

Below is a `Java` implementation of this logic with a DP. The variables `step` and `toGo` correspond to `M` and `K` respectively. I tried running it with some random numbers but low.

> Note : You would need to update the static array dimensions as well
>   when using huge values of M.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld{


    public static int step = 4;
    public static long[][] dMem = new long[100][100];

     public static void main(String []args){

        int toGo = 30;
        int max = toGo;
        int min = toGo/step;
        long temp = 0;

        long count = 0;
        for(int i = max; i >= min; i--){
            temp = nSteps(i, toGo);
            temp = temp == -1 ? 0 : temp;
            count += temp;
           // System.out.println(count+"\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Num of ways = "+count);
     }

     public static long nSteps( int n, int toGo ){

         long steps = 0, temp = 0;
         //System.out.println(" n = "+n+" toGo = "+toGo);
         if( n == toGo ) return 1;
         if( n > toGo || n <= 0 || toGo <= 0) return -1;
         if( dMem[n][toGo] != 0 ) return dMem[n][toGo];
         for( int i = 1; i <= step; i++){
             temp = nSteps( n-1, toGo-i );
             temp = temp == -1 ? 0 : temp;
             steps += temp;
         }
         steps = steps == 0 ? -1 : steps;
         dMem[n][toGo] = steps;
         return steps;
     }
}
```

Comment: What's the running time of this algorithm? Since I need only count of combinations can we have one formula which do that?

Comment: Let me see. I should be able to come up with one. I just need to check if we can reap something out of DP as I start from max, where all subsets are but single elements. We should gradually move on from there decreasing the no of total subsets by 1.

Comment: Have updated with a Java implementation of what I suggested. I really am not sure how the ranges would be handled as pointed out by @Davis the range could be huge(Nothing near long ~ 10^18).